# Hiding labels in bing map control api

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, bing-maps

I am using silver light bing map control api for windows phone 7. I am new to it. I could not get any api I can use for hiding the street labels in the map. Is there some way to achieve the same?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think, this link may be helpful, which talks about labels in the map to be displayed.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsphonetrainingcourse_usingbingmapslab_topic2.aspx

http://www.bing.com/blogs/site_blogs/b/maps/archive/2009/12/02/bing-maps-adds-streetside-enhanced-bird-s-eye-photosynth-and-more.aspx